# Why does Django's RelatedManager not cache the object the lookup was called from, on the destination object?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-related-manager

If I have the following models:

```
class Fubar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Related(models.Model):
    fubar = models.ForeignKey(Fubar)
```

I would expect that the ORM would magically cache the parent Fubar object if I accessed Related using .related_set:

```
fubar = Fubar.objects.all()[0]
related = fubar.related_set.all()[0]
related.fubar
```

That results in 3 queries, where I would expect it to only result in 2, since related.fubar could be optimised in this context to be the same object I called a RelatedManager on.

Comment: This is fixed in django 1.5 - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5-beta-1/#caching-of-related-model-instances

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I'm not sure why this doesn't work (except maybe magic reduction), you could easily avoid the extra query with

```
fubar.related_set.select_related('fubar')[0]
```

Comment: That does help, thanks. I was hoping it would be fubar's exact object/state, since in the current instance I am fetching and caching other information on the fubar object. I will just have to maintain my own cache of objects and lookup using the fubar_id.

Answer (score 0):

In django 1.4 they are introducing [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) which will automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.